# Fancybox (jQuery) is not displaying on first click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web

In a web application, I have used jQuery Fancybox as detailed at: http://fancybox.net/howto

Default.aspx code:

```
 <a id="lnkAddPart" href ="Part.aspx" runat ="server" >
  <div id="Div1" class="button" runat="server">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnAddRecord" ToolTip="Add Record" CssClass="image" ImageUrl="../img/tlb_list_addrecord.gif" runat="server" OnClick="BtnAddRecord_Click" />
  </div>
 </a>
```

In server side code of this button click, I called below jQuery method:

```
function AddPartList() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#lnkAddPart").fancybox({
                    'scrolling': 'no',
                    'width': 452,
                    'height': 225,
                    'type': 'iframe'
                });
            });
        }
```

It shows Part.aspx page in fancy box style.
But, It shows that fancy box on second click event. I mean, on first click it didn't open the fancy box.
What is the issue with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not put `document.read`y in `AddPartList`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#lnkAddPart").fancybox({
          'scrolling': 'no',
          'width': 452,
          'height': 225,
          'type': 'iframe'
      });
});
```

Comment: If i remove $(document).ready() frm AddPartList function then it didn't work. Fancybox didn't appear at all.